# Cocoaアプリのarchive(.app)後の挙動がおかしい

Tags: objective-c, macos

Obj-CでCocoaアプリを開発しています。
xcode上でrunした時は正常に動作しますが、.appにした後実行すると挙動がおかしくなります。
常駐アプリとしてカーソルの現在位置の値を用いているのですが、どうも値が取得できていないようです。
（＊システム環境設定で、アプリケーションにコンピュータの制御を許可にしています。)
原因がわからないため、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。